# ajax call controller in yii (javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

For some reason this doesnt work and I can't find a way to make it work!

on my controller named "ExplicacaoController" I have this:

```
public function accessRules()
...
'actions'=>array('index','view', 'test', 'ajaxrequest'),
...
public function actionAjaxRequest()
    {
      $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
      $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
      echo "something";

      Yii::app()->end();
    }
```

On my view I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:    "<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('explicacaoController/ajaxRequest'); ?>",
      data:  {val1:1,val2:2},
      success: function(msg){
           alert("Sucess")
          },
      error: function(xhr){
      alert("failure"+xhr.readyState+this.url)

      }
    });
...
```

What happens is that I allways get this error:

```
failure4<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('explicacaoController/ajaxRequest'); ?>
```

I really need some help with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to put

```
<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('Explicacao/ajaxRequest'); ?>
```

instead of

```
<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('explicacaoController/ajaxRequest'); ?>
```

The thing is in create url you need to put the Controller ID not the Controller full name.

If it's not working you could try both `Explicacao/ajaxRequest` or `explicacao/ajaxRequest` because your rout could be case sensitive depending on your conf

Comment: Could we see your url rules from the config? And did you try 'actions'=>array('index','view', 'test', 'ajaxRequest'), putting upper case for "ajaxrequest" ?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
url: $(location).attr('pathname') + '?r=anyControllerId/actionId',
```

This will get the path name of the current URL